# Error while including bean from org.springframewrok.orm jar file in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to make a crud application using Spring MVC and JPA with hibernate as a service provider.I already have a working CRUD application using spring MVC and jdbc.So I decided to make changes in already built application only

But the problem is when i include any class from org.springframewrok.orm jar file in beans.xml of spring it gives me HTTP 404- resource not found error. What could be the possible reasons??

I am using org.springframewrok.orm 3.1.1 release file.

Comment: Show to your server logfiles dor exceptions and post it if you find any.

Comment: As Jens mention, provide more information including:
- beans.xml file snippet
- which class is included?
- exception messages
- container/AS version